# I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Nothing shown after logging in

Tags: login, 16.04

Nothing shown after logging in. Only Desktop picture (is it right? the purple one) is shown. that's all.

How can I do about this? I normally used Ubuntu 15.10. But Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't.

My system is

```
- Intel core-i7 6700k
- Asus Z170-A
- Samgsung DDR4 8GBx2
- Samgsung SSD 850 Pro 1TB
- nVidia Geforce 970
```

Comment: This might be related to your graphic card, maybe the solution provided [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) will help you

Comment: Videonauth, thank you for your help, however, that doesn't work for me. What a sad...

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution for myself.

In *Terminal*, type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
```

and then type:

```
setsid unity
```

It works perfectly for me.

I don't have to install the Nvidia 364 driver.